# ASP.NET Dynamic JavaScript File

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm writing a ASP.NET web application. It dosen't use Web Forms or MVC. It uses ASP.NET Routing to a Http Handler, and the handler just writes html to the HttpContext.

The final output of my html is something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ...
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Now, Instead of writing the (long) script into this page, I want to write it to another page, and then use the `src` of `script` element to reference it. The problem is, that the script is dynamic.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just place the location of the dynamic script inside the src?

I.e., if http://www.example.com/foo is your HTTP handler, can you make another HTTP handler, http://www.example.com/bar for the dynamic javascript?  You should be able to pass any parameters needed inside a query string.

Answer (score 0):

your script is dynamic => I assume it changes based on the user/context/date/time ??

you should set your Response.Charset (to UTF-8) & Response.ContentType (to text/javascript)